# Error. Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework is higher version than referenced assembly 'EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I have Visual Studio 2012 professional, nd i use to build web applications using these technologies:-

- asp.net mvc4.
- Entity framework version 5.

now i have installed an update to my visual studio to support asp.net mvc5, then i download this template http://www.campusmvp.net/blog/extended-template-for-asp-net-mvc-5-from-visual-studio-2012.

I have created a new asp.net mvc5 project based on the templete, but when i run the application i got this error:-

> Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses
>   'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' which has a higher version than
>   referenced assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  c:\Users....\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WebApplication3\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.1.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll    WebApplication3

now inside my application web.config file i have the following:-

```
configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  </configSections>
```

which means i am using EF 5 so why it is trying to reference EF6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ASP.NET Identity is using Entity Framework 6 (because you're using the EF implementation of it). The easiest solution would be to update EF to version 6. Another way (but I wouldn't call it nice) is to add an assembly redirect. Keep in mind that this way can introduce other problems.

If you don't use ASP.NET Identity at all (which is in the template by default), you could also remove all references and the code in the template, which references Identity..

Comment: thanks for the reply. but since i already have web projects inside my VS which are using EF 5, so will installing EF 6 inside my VS cause any problem for the web projects that are already using EF5 ? or installing EF6 will not affect EF5 ?

Comment: Upgrading to EF6 has [some impact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx). You'll need the appropriate NuGet package, ensure that System.Data.Entity.dll is removed, updating some namespaces and swapping EDMX models to code generation. In my opinion the last point is the hardest one if you use EDMX models.

Comment: Yes i am suing edmx . but in my case i do not want the old mvc-4 projects to use EF6 (at-least not at this stage) ,i want them to keep using EF5. i only want new projects which are based on MVC-5 to start using EF6. so there are no upgrade for the projects.. did u get mu point ?

Comment: Yes, got it. Are you using ASP.NET Identity in your old projects? If not, remove it from your project.

Comment: no i am not using asp.net identity inside the old projects, i even do not have references to it inside my old projects. so now if i create a new asp.net mvc5 then i install the EF6 , will the old projects which uses EF5 got affected ?, or it is normal to have different versions for EF inside the Visual Studio environment, and to have multiple projects using different EF versions inside the same dev machine?

Comment: Ok, than I would guess that the projects reference in each other in some way. If you have two projects in one solution using two different versions of EF and they are not referencing each other, they should not get affected ... but if they reference each other you get an error similar to the one you described above. It would be helpful if you could share your project structure (and what projects references which version of EF) and how the projects are related to each other.

Comment: no i am not sharing any projects together. i am talking about different solutions.

Comment: Then there should be no problem.

Comment: but now regarding the original problem ,, so i need to install EF-6 using Nuget for the new asp.net mvc-5 ? and this will not affect the old projects ,, is this correct ? second question, when i install EF-6 on the new project , will all the new projects be using EF-6 from now on? or VS will keep referencing EF-5 for any new project ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66666/discussion-between-horizon-net-and-john-g).